# How to set PythonPath/ UDF_Modules?

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have been trying to build my own Excel functions using Xlwings.

Using

```
$ xlwings quickstart myproject
```

would create a Python script in the same directory as the Excel xlsm file.

I want to put the Python script anywhere I want, like "D:\test0.py", so I did this on VBA Function Settings:

```
PYTHONPATH = "D:\test0.py"
UDF_MODULES = "test0"
```

Except for these two lines, I didn't change anything in Function Settings.

I got

> ImportError: No module named 'test0'

[image]

How do I import module from "D:\test0.py"?

Comment: `A Shot In the Dark` : I don't work with python. Just went through the docs.  Try changing `PYTHONPATH = "D:\test0.py"` to `UDF_PATH = "D:\test0.py"`

Comment: Also the name of the `.xlsm` and `.py` is the same? (test0.xlsm and test0.py)

Comment: @ Siddharth Thank you! .xlsm is the excle file, not the python sript. Btw, UDF_PATH would cause: Compile error: Variables not defined

Comment: yes i understood that. But both test0.xlsm and test0.py should be in the same directory else you need to specify a path using `UDF_PATH`. This is what I understood from the docs... http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html Maybe I am reading the wrong thing? Like I said, I do not work with python :P

Comment: Yes, I understand. But in Xlwings  VBA module, Function Settings even doesn't take UDF_PATH as a parameter, I would guess that UDF_PATH might be a mistake, what real in there should be PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I guess, I should take a step back and let a python expert help you out :)

Comment: BTW, I have subscribed to your question. I have been thinking for quite long to test waters in python but never got a chance and to be honest, I am now curious as to what the answer to your question might be :)

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: (Disclaimer: I've never used Python)  Is your path `D:\test0.py` (i.e. the file is `D:\test0.py\test0.py`), or is the path `D:\ `  (i.e. the file is `D:\test0.py`)?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I just read the documentation from the same site you were looking at (I looked at http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html ) and it is certainly confusing - the examples for `UDF_MODULES` use `UDF_PATH` instead!  My **guess** is that it is meant to be `UDF_MODULES`, with the path being specified by `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @YowE3K - sorry, I just noticed, the path is ''D:\'', the file is test0.py. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PYTHONPATH`, as the name says, is a path, not a file, i.e. you should be using

```
PYTHONPATH = "D:\"
```

`xlwings quickstart myproject` is still useful because it sets up the Excel file with the VBA module, even if you want to move out the python file later on.

Comment: Thank you! I tried
   PYTHONPATH = "D:\"
but got a new error: Run-time error '1000': python process exited before it was possible to create the interface object.

Comment: Looks like a small bug. Can you try `"D:\\"`

Comment: This answer does not work for me. I get the same error as the question states.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm new to Python / xlwings, but I hadn't realised how precise I needed to be. Had to set the Interpreter to `C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe` and PYTHONPATH to `C:\\Anaconda3` and both the UDFs and RunPython VBA calls started working.