# xlwings Addin Errors - "Invalid procedure call or argument" / "File not found"

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to run a python sub using the [xlwings addin (v0.14.0)](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/index.html). I have set the following parameters in the ribbon of the addin:

```
Interpreter: pythonw.exe
PYTHONPATH: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\VirtualEnv\
UDF Modules: mdlGetHistoricalData
```

When I press Import Functions I receive the "**Invalid procedure call or argument 5**" error.

If I change the `Interpreter` parameter to be blank (it should default to pythonw.exe) I receive the error "**File not found: xlwings32-0.14.0.dll 53**", this file is currently located inside the virtual environment package specified in `PYTHONPATH`. I have tried placing it in my Python project location as well, but I still recieve this error.

Is there something wrong with my parameters in the addin? Or is there something else wrong here?

**Facts**:

- I'm using xlwings 0.14.0 in my virtual environment and the ribbons
  version is identical.
- I'm using Python 3.6 in my virtual environment
- I've used the "@xw.sub" identifier in my Python script
- I have also tried stepping through Py.CallUDF and RunPython in VBA and receive identical errors

Comment: Look more closely at the docs: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-settings: Interpreter is the full path and PYTHONPATH is where your modules are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Felix. I made the required changes and now I get an error which reads: "Python process exited before it was possible to create the interface object ... the command .. Working Dir: <unspecified> 1000"

Comment: I found the answer to my problem in another one of your answers. I had my PYTHON path set to Z:\ instead of Z:\\

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983144/xlwings-udfs-how-to-set-pythonpath-udf-modules-correctly